# MySQL DB Sequencing For Loops

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a situation where I make multiple DB calls in the result set of another query. I am using CodeIgniter to process these like so:

```
$sql = "SOME QUERY";

$query = $this->db->query($sql);

if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
   foreach ($query->result() as $row) 
  {
      $someID = $row->id;
      // another function that makes another DB call to return a result
      $anotherValue = anotherDBQueryFunction($someID);
  }
}
```

My main question is does this situation create sleeping MySQL connections, waiting the PHP to Finnish the main query before closing it? Is this a bad design?

Comment: generaly speaking, if you're running nested queries in a loop, and the "innner" query depends on data from the "outer" query, you can almost always rewrite both queries into a single `JOIN`ed query and generally be far more efficient doing so.

Comment: Yes because this is O(2*N)... this means the more data in the outer loop will fire more Querys in the inner loop... and you could trigger an anti flood limit within the MySQL server and MySQL kills your thread..

Comment: The "inner" queries are much faster if they are run separately, but I'm more concerned about massive connections. Plus there are some things that I can't do a join on. Massive Joins = Longer Queries.

Comment: JOINS without indexes will indeed kill your performance then it would be better to separate your querys so you can use PRIMARY KEY.. but most likly you query like this SELECT * ... and you still are using MyISAM because you heard stories that InnoDB is slow..